# QtcpSocket without signals/slots

Tags: qt, qt4, qtcpsocket

Is it possible to use **QTcpSocket** without using **readyRead** slots ?

I tried this code for reading datas from a tcp server :

```
QByteArray ba;

forever
{
sck.waitForReadyRead();
ba.append( sck.readAll() );

if (sck.bytesAvailable() == 0)
  break;
}
```

but sometimes I don't receive all the datas from server !?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is possible. TCP is stream-oriented, you can't exit from the iteration like that. You have an example in [QAbstractSocket](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qabstractsocket.html) documentation.

As you can see, you'll have to keep reading until the connection is closed (the [waitForReadyRead](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qabstractsocket.html#waitForReadyRead)() method returns false) or until you send some termination sequence, that is up to you.

Comment: You're damn right... My fault, I focused on QTcpSocket !! One again I have to RTMFM first :(